# Regular expression with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression for checking numbers.

I should be able to identify the following:

- 999
- 99.99
- 99,99
- 99 9/9

But not the following 99M, 99BN, 99$.

So I thought this might work: 
 `string rule1 = @"\b[0-9]+(?(.|,|\n){0,1}[0-9]+)\b";`

`[0-9]+` the first part says: I need 1 or more digits.

`(?(.|,|\n){0,1}[0-9]*)` In this second part my intention was to express a condition:

If a point or a comma or a space comes after the first part then I need one or more numbers after the point, comma or space. But since I don't know a lot about regular expressions I'm stuck and getting a run-time exception.

Comment: In your last case, you have a space in the number. Is that intentional? How would you determine that from two separate numbers?

Comment: It's not a line break. It's suposed to be a fractional representation like one and a half 1 1/2

Comment: I'm confused by your example, first you give 4 valid notations, and then you state exclusions as if anything implies them? Anyway this regex covers what you want: `\b[1-9][0-9]*([,.][0-9]+| *[1-9][0-9]*/[1-9][0-9]*)?\b`. If you want to match numeric ranges, then see RegexNumRangeGen on Codeplex.

Comment: And what runtime exception are you getting? With what input?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how you want to handle the last case, since as I said in a comment, there's a space in your example. But assuming that was supposed to be a line break, I believe something like this should work.

```
(\b\d+(\.|,|\/)?\d+\b)[^$]
```

Broken down:

```
(
\b           Word break
\d+          Any digit character (equivalent to your [0-9]), matched one or more times
(\.|,|\/)?   A period (escaped), comma, or slash (escaped), matched zero or one time.
\d+          Any digit character (equivalent to your [0-9]), matched one or more times
\b           Word break
)
[^$]         Avoid the last case, of 99$
```

I've tested this to the extent I can [here](http://regexr.com/39to7).

Comment: Note that an escape sequence is unnecessary for a slash.